# Blazor revert value when backend update fails

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a JavaScript plugin on the frontend that handles figuring out how to update a numeric input field.  Upon completion, it invokes the event change via `dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`.  However due to other issues with the plugin, occasionally it generates invalid data (such as a NaN) that fails on the backend to process.  When this happens, the frontend UI still retains the rejected value from the system.

An example from my code

```
        public async Task UpdateGrade(ChangeEventArgs eventArgs, GradeModel myGrade)
        {
            bool Success;
            if (int.TryParse(eventArgs.Value.ToString(), out int newGrade))
                Success = BackendService.UpdateGrade(myGrade, newGrade);

            if (!Success)
            {
                // Log the failure..
                // Tell the frontend to restore the original value.
            }

            StateHasChanged();
        }
```

If the eventArgs.Value happens to be "NaN", this will fail the TryParse and we never will send it to the backend (where it will fail there as well for not being a integer).  But the front end may still display the wrong value.  Only getting out and back into the item on the page will update it.

I've tried to reassign the myGrade to itself which doesn't work.  The only work around that has been successful was to make the model allow the value to be null, set it to null, cal StateHasChanged and then set it back to the original value.  This seems like more of a hack than the proper way to restore the value.